# Pre Computing shadows, advantages/disadvantages?

Tags: shadows

Today I was looking at a still frame of a game, and noticed that all of the shadows were dynamic (created per frame). As we know, shadows can be quite expensive.
I was wondering why shadows could not be simply mapped at run time for non moving objects, and then only do dynamic shadows for players, vehicles, etc.
What are the advantages/disadvantages of doing this?

Comment: Quake 2 does this; Carmack indicated that there are really no disadvantages - just really good looking shadows that are fast.

Comment: You can't have dynamic light sources if you bake the shadows from terrain/scenery can you?

Comment: What if you have notmoving house and static light source. And you bake out house shadow to texture of the ground. What would happen if you move with your player to the shadow of house? Player won't be "shadowed" - am I right?

Comment: Differences in quality and visual appearance between dynamic and static shadows is the main one I can think of; this kind of visual discontinuity can be quite jarring once you start noticing it.

Comment: @ClassicThunder Quake 2 does. IIRC it has the pre-calculated static lights and then renders the dynamic lights to another shadow texture. The dynamic texture is minute (256x256 for the entire level I think) - but bilinear filtering smooths it out nicely.

Comment: @zacharmarz I think you just cheat and use the shadow of whatever they are standing on - it should look 'good enough'; very much so in a single player game.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson You don't understand me - lets take character standing in shadow of a tree. Tree has some spaces in shadow. Light source isn't pointing directly from above, but from "45 degrees slope". So for example characters head is not in shadow and on his body should be shadow with gaps. This won't be easy to achieve. But with dynamic shadows (for tree), this is the same as for what ever other object.

Comment: @zacharmarz that's what I meant by 'good enough'; not good enough for a AAA title; but maybe acceptable for an indie one. Either way you can trim down the number of dynamic lights with precalc (especially in angular/indoor/futuristic environments).

Comment: There are some systems that use both.  Unity, for example, supports "dual lightmaps" where distant objects are solely using dynamic lights, but close up it just uses precalculated bounce and real time shadows.  http://unity3d.com/unity/engine/lighting.html

Comment: @JonathanDickinson: Quake2 is also 13+ years old. Doom3, if I recall correctly, used entirely dynamic shadows.

Comment: @NicolBolas so is Wolfenstein - but our primary rendering technique still comes from it, doesn't it?

Comment: @JonathanDickinson: Our "primary rendering technique" does not come from Wolfenstein. It was not rendering triangles of any kind. There was no depth buffer. While it created similar *effects*, the actual rendering techniques were vastly different from what we use today. In any case, my point is that saying that Carmack once said that there were no downsides to static shadows means nothing. Since he later *abandoned them*. You're trying to make a point with outdated data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disadvantages:

- Lightmaps are very large textures. If you have enough processing to make all shadows dynamic you can probably use the memory for something else.
- Non unified lighting model. Some lighting models like deferred don't mix well with prebaked shadows.
- Light mappers are usually very slow. You need to wait few hours to preview lighting changes in the scene.
- You can't pre-bake lights in case that light sources are moving even if everything else the scene is static.

Advantages:

- You can have much higher quality shadows and lighting.
- Faster processing
- Virtually unlimited number of light sources can be used